# Any advantage of always using suffix 'f' for floats in C++?

Tags: c++

Any advantage of always using suffix 'f' for floats in C++?

From one hand my code gets mess, I mean I have lots of math formulas
and imagine instead of writing simply 1, to write 1.0f. It would clutter
the code.

But I wonder if there is an optimization or other aspect on this?

Thanks

Comment: 1 is int, 1.0 is double, 1.0f is float.

Comment: `1.f` or even just `1.` to make it a `double` for floating point calculation instead of integer arithmetic.

Comment: `1.0f` would be float, `1.0` would be double. No advantage as far as I know.

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes it becomes *necessary*.

Consider this function template:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T a, T b);

float get_value(); //consider this too!
```

Now see this:

```
f(get_value(), 1);   //compilation error
f(get_value(), 1.0); //compilation error
f(get_value(), 1.0f); //okay
```

In the first two calls, template argument deduction fails, so they don't compile. See the error yourself at [ideone](http://ideone.com/ISxwI).

Note that the type of `1` is `int`, and `1.0` is `double` whereas `1.0f` is `float`.

Comment: And this dear friends would have been a perfect opportunity to introduce the std::identity template, but that was removed during C++0x, but would have solved such and similar cases very nicely. what a shame...

Answer (score 1):

The compiler almost certainly figures it out so that there's no run-time performance penalty.

Reasons to be explicit are to avoid compiler warnings about implicit conversions, to avoid conversions that may behave unexpectedly, and for a specific types to be deduced in a type deduction context or to force a specific overload to be called.

Here's an example where the source wants to express a value as a fraction, but gets the wrong value because the literals are the wrong type:

```
float a = 3/4; // produces 0.0f instead of 0.75f
```

Here's a warning caused by an implicit conversion:

```
tmp.cpp:4:15: warning: implicit conversion loses floating-point precision:
      'double' to 'float' [-Wconversion]
    float a = 0.1;
          ~   ^~~
```

Here's a case of ambiguous overload error caused by not being specific:

```
tmp.cpp:6:5: error: call to 'foo' is ambiguous
    foo(1);
    ^~~
tmp.cpp:2:6: note: candidate function
void foo(unsigned char a);
     ^
tmp.cpp:3:6: note: candidate function
void foo(float b);
     ^
```

Answer (score 0):

`1.0` or `1.` is a `double` constant

`1.0f` is a `float` constant

There is a difference.

Answer (score 0):

It can eliminate warnings.

By the way, depending on your compiler, behind the scene floats get promoted to double for calculations.

Comment: Or both might be promoted to some even larger type.

Answer (score 0):

One other use for specifying double vs. float is a left over from FORTRAN that may or may not plague your compiler.  In days of yore, FORTRAN only stored data to the precision you specified leaving trash in the unspecified bytes beyond your last digit.  It was quite possible to code x = 1.0 and have x really equal 1.0987659987623, depending on the type of "x" (which in FORTRAN would have been a single precision floating point number).